# Add "close" button to a bootstrap tab content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, tabs

I'm having trouble adding a "close" button to my Bootstrap tab content. Not only should the tabs open and close on hover, but I have to add a button to allow users to click and close the tab.

```
<!-- SIDE NAV -->
    <div class="col-xs-3 hidden-xs">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="side-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="full-width">
                        <a href="#accueil" aria-controls="accueil" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="full-width">
                        <a href="#connaitre-la-ccmv" aria-controls="connaitre-la-ccmv" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB 2</a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content col-xs-9 hidden-xs">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane row" id="accueil">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h5 class="title-tab">TAB CONTENT 1</h5>
                    <ul class="list-tab">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Some text</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Some other text</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="button" class="close">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

Can someone please help with the js part ? I haven't found anything about it in the Bootstrap documentation...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can manipulate the close button in jquery and put a style on it in the css by hiding the tab when the button is clicked.

use this in your css to hide the tab.

```
.display_none{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Use this in your jquery code.

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.tab-content').addClass('display_none');
});
```

Refer to this instructions
[enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Edited jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it created another problem :/ since the tab-content is now "display : none", it won't show again on hover unless I refresh. Can I undo the "display : none" on hover ?

Comment: what button do you want to restore the display? I mean is there any button that can restore your tab? if so just repeat the code above and modify the selector and change the display into display: inline !important;

Answer (score -3):

It very simple man just remove active class with JS put this code below:-

```
$("button").click(function(){$("div").removeClass("active");});
```

Comment: this will select all "div" elements on the page and remove the active class.  It may have unintended consequences to other elements on the page.